# How to Colorize Events in Pdist correlation of Matlab?

Tags: matlab, data-visualization

Output of `plot(mat2gray(pdist(data, 'correlation')));`

[image]

I see there about 3-5 trends, which I would like to visualize better. 
I think the `plot` may not be the optimum here. 
Its `imshow(squareform(pdist(data, 'correlation')))` (equivalent to `imshow(squareform(pdist(data, 'correlation'), 'tomatrix'))`) is the following based on Dan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35750880/54964).
Image with normalized `pdist` values i.e. `imshow(squareform( mat2gray(pdist(data, 'correlation')), 'tomatrix') ); colormap('parula');`

[image]

However, I have some difficulties in interpreting the picture. 
There seems to be like three eigenvalues if you consider a dark place like an eigenvalue. 
What should I put here to the axes?

---

How can you visualize the output of dist correlation better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
imshow(squareform(pdist(data, 'correlation')))
```

You might have to massage the result before calling `imshow` to make it either range form `0` to `1` or to be of type `uint8` and range from `0` to `255`

Comment: I added an output of your command in the body. I have some difficulties in interpreting the result. - My data range is already between [0,1]. `pdist` gives values [1E-6, 1.76]. So doing `mat2gray(pdist(data, 'correlation'));` keeps the plot also in [0,1].

Comment: Please, see the 2nd figure in the body of the question. Does the dark low sloping line mean that the correlation is -1? I am trying to think which side the figure really is.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, I find it odd that calling `pdist` with `'correlation'` returns values outside a range of `-1` and `1`. Your first task should be to understand what the numbers mean individually. Secondly, you need to add a colorbar to that image please.

Comment: Yes, sure. Colorbar is there now. Range is [0,1] which is ok. Yes, you are right. The dark downward sloping curve means 0 correlation. Now, I try to think what the upper-right corner 0 correlation means. It seems to be equivalent to the noisy data in the 1st figure.

Comment: @Masi no the colors don't match the correlations directly because you normalized them (i.e. `mat2gray`)... The main diagonal must surely have a correlation of 1

Comment: How can you normalize the colorbar to my normalized values? It would be bad mistake to use wrong colorbar with values.

Comment: @Masi step 1 is to understand what the results of `pdist` are. You need to understand what those numbers mean before anything else is useful. For example, if it was correlation I might make the colour bar range from -1 to 1 but then I would also use a different normalization. If the range is unbounded then make the colour bar range from the min to the max (of the numbers from `pdist`) by changing the tickmarklabels of the colorbar axis

Comment: You are so right! Do you have any sources about the topic in choosing the appropriate colormaps mathematically? I know the situation exactly in my original source but to understand how it becomes in square correlation matrix, ..., I do not know yet.

Comment: @Masi I'm sorry I can't help you any further. Your question was how to display the data and I have answered that. Your new question is how to interpret your data and since you have provided no context what so ever about your data no one but you is able to provide any insight. There are no tricks regarding the colorbar, no maths. Just apply exactly the inverse normalization.